# Error querying special character

Tags: php

I have a DB with 4 columns (Id, name, description, price), I stamp them with a php file and they all work except for the price column that return null because it has € as a character, I tried to set utf-8 encoding using:

```
 header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
 mysqli_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

But without luck.

This is my php file:

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");
 mysqli_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prodotti";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();


    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What do I need to change in order to display the correct value of price instead of null?

**EDIT**
The Price column is of type: VARCHAR (50) 
I also tried TEXT but without luck

**EDIT 2**
This is the result of the `query show variables like '%charac%';` On the DB

[image]

Comment: Is the € stored the right way in your databasE?

Comment: yes I see it correctly on my DB

Comment: what if you try to save it with its html name  "&euro;" ?

Comment: could you show desc table?

Comment: @Akis already tried but since I output json data I only see &euro; and not the symbol

Comment: I forgot to say:
The Price column is of type: VARCHAR (50) I also tried TEXT but without luck

Comment: does row contain the value?

Comment: every row has a value like: 900 + € 12,00      
If i remove the € I can see the values correctly on the php query

Comment: for mySQL before 5.0.7:

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
or mySQL 5.0.7 and newer:

mysql_set_charset("utf8");

Comment: @Signo oh sorry i didn't notice json how about its ascii then ? \20AC should do the job

Comment: @SebriZouhaier tried to set both but no luck, it still returns null..

Comment: @Akis So I should set \20AC instead of €?

Comment: yes json will understand it and convert it. Look also this http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm for ascii codes and this previous similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310191/character-encoding-from-utf8-json-to-iso-8859-1

Comment: can you send the result of this query : 
show variables like '%charac%';

Comment: @Akis thank you for the help but still I can't get out of this :P I tried to set one of the € to \20AC but the result on the php is \\20AC

Comment: @SebriZouhaier i added the result of the query on the edit